# LEFT JOIN AND multiple conditions mysql not working

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a problem with this sql query in mysql

```
SELECT
g.PROFILE_INFO_ID,g.ADDRESS,
g.DATE_NAISS,g.CIN,g.PRENOM,
g.NOM,g.MLE_C,g.BADGE_ID,
g.GRADE_ID,g.SECTION_ID,
g.SERVICE_ID,lp.id_pointage,
lp.autorisation,lp.date_p_in,
lp.date_p_out,lp.image_p_in,
lp.image_p_out,lp.UNITE,
lp.ID_BADGE,lp.UNITE_ID
FROM
profile_info AS g
LEFT JOIN last_pointage AS lp ON g.BADGE_ID = lp.ID_BADGE
WHERE 
DATE_FORMAT((lp.date_p_in), '%d-%m-%Y') LIKE DATE_FORMAT((NOW()), '%d-%m-%Y')
AND (
g.SECTION_ID = (SELECT SECTION_ID from section WHERE section.SECTION_NAME like 'TOPO') and
g.SERVICE_ID = (SELECT SERVICE_ID from service WHERE service.SERVICE_NAME like 'SIGR')
)
```

The result of the query is :

[image]

but when i remove the Date Condition : `DATE_FORMAT((lp.date_p_in), '%d-%m-%Y') LIKE DATE_FORMAT((NOW()), '%d-%m-%Y')

```
SELECT
g.PROFILE_INFO_ID,g.ADDRESS,
g.DATE_NAISS,g.CIN,g.PRENOM,
g.NOM,g.MLE_C,g.BADGE_ID,
g.GRADE_ID,g.SECTION_ID,
g.SERVICE_ID,lp.id_pointage,
lp.autorisation,lp.date_p_in,
lp.date_p_out,lp.image_p_in,
lp.image_p_out,lp.UNITE,
lp.ID_BADGE,lp.UNITE_ID
FROM
profile_info AS g
LEFT JOIN last_pointage AS lp ON g.BADGE_ID = lp.ID_BADGE
WHERE 
 (
g.SECTION_ID = (SELECT SECTION_ID from section WHERE section.SECTION_NAME like 'TOPO') and
g.SERVICE_ID = (SELECT SERVICE_ID from service WHERE service.SERVICE_NAME like 'SIGR')
)`
```

i get what i want but i want the result just today date :

[image]

the tables : 
[image]

can you help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rest of your query is doing what you want, maybe try

```
SELECT g.PROFILE_INFO_ID,
       g.ADDRESS,
       g.DATE_NAISS,
       g.CIN,
       g.PRENOM,
       g.NOM,
       g.MLE_C,
       g.BADGE_ID,
       g.GRADE_ID,
       g.SECTION_ID,
       g.SERVICE_ID,
       lp.id_pointage,
       lp.autorisation,
       lp.date_p_in,
       lp.date_p_out,
       lp.image_p_in,
       lp.image_p_out,
       lp.UNITE,
       lp.ID_BADGE,
       lp.UNITE_ID
FROM profile_info AS g
LEFT JOIN last_pointage AS lp ON g.BADGE_ID = lp.ID_BADGE
WHERE DATE(lp.date_p_in) = CURDATE()
  AND ( g.SECTION_ID =
         (SELECT SECTION_ID
          FROM SECTION
          WHERE section.SECTION_NAME LIKE 'TOPO')
       AND g.SERVICE_ID =
         (SELECT SERVICE_ID
          FROM service
          WHERE service.SERVICE_NAME LIKE 'SIGR') );
```

It looks like the date in the date_p_in column is in a pretty standard format so a simple approach might be best (unless you're expecting some dates to be in weird formats?).

You can put the date condition in the join as Gordon suggested, as well, but you'd potentially get all the rows with null values in the date_p_in column for all the rows where the date is not today. Just depends what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions on all but the first table, in a series of `left join`s, needs to go in the `on` clauses, not the `where` clause.

Also, your date arithmetic is just bad.  You should be using built-in date/time functions -- that is why they are there.  So the `from` should look like:

```
FROM profile_info g LEFT JOIN
     last_pointage lp
     ON g.BADGE_ID = lp.ID_BADGE AND
        lp.date_p_in = curdate()
WHERE . . .
```

If `date_p_in` could have a time component, use the `date()` function.